# Flot: Weird error pops up when attempting to draw graph on page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

The graph doesn't draw and the console throws this: `Uncaught Error: Invalid dimensions for plot, width = 1350, height = 0` is the error.

I tried recreating the error on a JSFiddle but was unable to do so, however here is what it should resemble: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kzg3r/57/)

Some notes on this error:

- Sometimes on the first x page loads, the graph will be drawn, and then it will cease after throwing up that error.
- Here is the full error:

  `Uncaught Error: Invalid dimensions for plot, width = 1350, height = 0 jquery.flot.js:119`

  `Canvas.resize jquery.flot.js:119`

  `Canvas jquery.flot.js:98`

  `setupCanvases jquery.flot.js:1261`

  `Plot jquery.flot.js:674`

  `$.plot jquery.flot.js:3039`

  `visc_graph active-scripts.js:45`

  `(anonymous function) active-scripts.js:346`

  `k jquery.min.js:2`

  `l.fireWith jquery.min.js:2`

  `p.extend.ready jquery.min.js:2`

  `D jquery.min.js:2`

And it seems to get thrown from here in the jquery.flot source:

```
    Canvas.prototype.resize = function(width, height) {

        if (width <= 0 || height <= 0) {
            throw new Error("Invalid dimensions for plot, width = " + width + ", height = " + height);
Uncaught Error: Invalid dimensions for plot, width = 1350, height = 0
        }
```

- EDIT:More information:
  Unlike the JSFiddle linked above, I am plotting multiple graphs using that function - something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Kzg3r/58/), however, when I'd created separate functions for each `placeholder` div, this did not occur.
- Calling the graphing function from the console i.e. `visc_graph(2,3,'#placeholder');` seems to work fine :(

I've been struggling with this for a while as I have no way of diagnosing what the actual cause of this is. Any input as to how I could approach solving this would be immensely appreciated.

UPDATE:

- [Here is the Fiddle with the DOM that manages to capture the same error](http://jsfiddle.net/Kzg3r/67/)

Comment: Do you have your plot call wrapped in a `.ready(handler)` - http://api.jquery.com/ready/.  My guess would be that javascript is firing before the DOM is fully loaded.

Comment: Yes I do @Mark. Refer to the Fiddle, it is pretty bare bones. The code is wrapped in the doc ready handler: `$(document).ready(function() {//code})`

Comment: The code calling for the plotting that is.

Answer (score 5):

That error arises when Flot can't determine the size of the placeholder div.  This can happen in several ways, but generally it means that you called `$.plot` before the placeholder was in the DOM.

This can happen, as @Mark suggested, if you're calling `$.plot` before the document is ready, but it can also happen in other ways.  Are your plots held in tabs, accordions, dialog boxes, or any other widget whose contents are hidden on page load?  If so, that's likely implemented by leaving the content div out of the DOM, which means that the plot placeholder is also outside of the DOM and can't be measured.

There's really no other reason why this error would arise, so if you still don't see the problem you'll need to post more of your code - in particular the DOM portion - so we can understand what's happening.

Comment: Hi, I've pasted the DOM (and have managed to recreate the error by doing so) [in this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kzg3r/67/)

It's fairly messy, but the graphing functions are at the bottom of the javascript, and the only CSS belongs to the placeholder for the graph. 

Ask if you would need the Fiddle toned down some more to inspect better.

Comment: Not sure you really recreated it; your example is breaking jsfiddle.  By including `<head>`/`<body>` tags and reloading jquery in the html panel, jsfiddle isn't happy.

Comment: @DNS yes I see the same thing. I'm going to clean up my code significantly and try to recreate with the most minimal case, will post back when I do so.

Answer (score 2):

I had same issue last night, what I did to fix this issue was to set the placeholder div size using css something like this:

```
<style type="text/css">
   #placeholder{
      width:100%;
      height:200px;
  }
</style>

<div id="content" class="demo-container">
   <div id="placeholder" class="demo-placeholder"></div>
</div>
```

after setting div size it started working.

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks for your input John, however, I did however already give my div a width and a height before attempting to plot.